# бургер меню на js

Tags: javascript, html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста оптимальное решение. Умею делать на jquery, *но хочу научиться* на **чистом js**.

Answer (score 2):

механизм собственно не сложный

для проверки: https://jsfiddle.net/mn2wc0k9/21/

нажмите **выполнить код** потом разверните на **всю страницу** а  браузер сожмите до/меньше 640px увидите кнопку при клике на которую показывается меню

```js
document.getElementById("trigger").onclick = function() {
  open()
};

function open() {
  document.getElementById("menu").classList.toggle("show");
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 50px;
}

ul a {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

@media (max-width:640px) {
  .menu {
    display: none;
  }
  .trigger {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .trigger i {
    display: block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 6px;
    margin: 4px auto;
    background: #222;
  }
  .show {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <span id="trigger" class="trigger">
  <i></i>
  <i></i>
  <i></i>
</span>
  <ul id="menu" class="menu">
    <li><a href="">item1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">item2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">item3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```